# How do I build Eidete from source?

Tags: 12.04, compiling

I have recently become interested in [Eidete Screencaster](https://launchpad.net/eidete), and I am trying to compile it from source on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

After running `bzr branch lp:eidete`, I navigated into the `~/eidete` directory and found an `INSTALL` file with the following contents:

```
Dependencies:
    gtk+-3.0
    libwnck-3.0
    gstreamer-interfaces-0.10
    gstreamer-0.10
    gstreamer-pbutils-0.10
    granite
    xtst
    gdk-x11-3.0

Installation:
    bzr branch lp:eidete
    cd eidete
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr
    make
    sudo make install
```

After some investigation, I believe I have correctly satisfied all package dependencies, as I no longer get complaints about that when I run the `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr` step. However, when I then try to run `make`, the build fails with the following output:

```
christopher@XyzPrecise:~/eidete/build$ make
[  7%] Generating src/eidete.c, src/Widgets/countdown.c, src/Widgets/keyview.c, src/Widgets/selectionarea.c, src/Widgets/end_dialog.c, src/desktop_launcher.c, build/src/Config.c
error: Package `granite' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
make[2]: *** [src/eidete.c] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/eidete.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The step before that previously complained that I didn't have the necessary version of Vala installed, so I installed it from the [Vala PPA](https://launchpad.net/~vala-team/+archive/ppa) and didn't get the warning from `cmake` anymore after that. All other packages required I installed from the Ubuntu Precise repositories, including `libgranite-dev`.

So, why is `make` complaining about `granite`, and how do I correct this so I can build Eidete successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is likely that you have an old version of `libgranite`. To get the latest version, you might have to add the elementary daily PPA as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgranite-dev
```

Alternatively, you get can the latest deb's from https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/daily/+packages.

Please note that in that PPA there are daily builds of Eidete, so compiling from source would be unnecessary.

Also, if you'd like it to be easily removable through `apt`, you can nest the debian/ directory of [lp:~elementary-os/eidete/deb-packaging](https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/eidete/deb-packaging) into the root of your Eidete source directory. You can simply copy the files there once they've been branched. Also, note that the packages `devscripts` and `dpkg-dev` are needed to create Debian packages.

Comment: Yep, the problem appeared to be an out-of-date `libgranite-dev`. Thanks!